# Specify Monitor For Linux Console

Tags: linux, nvidia, framebuffer

Does the kernel, framebuffer, or a framebuffer driver (uvesafb) have an option to specify the video-card output to use?

The kernel only outputs to one monitor:

- Kernel message buffer (before and after framebuffer initialization)
- Framebuffer (if specified in kernel command-line)
- Virtual console (tty's etc)

Note: I have no issues with X-windows configuration (only the console)

Kernel options (with fb): 
`kernel /stable root=/dev/sda3 video=uvesafb:mtrr:3,ywrap,1920x1200-32@60`

Kernel options (no-fb): 
`kernel /stable root=/dev/sda3`

System Information:

- Gentoo Linux (x86_64)
- Kernel: linux-3.3.8-gentoo
- Video Card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 (2x DVI outputs)
- Driver: NVIDIA Driver Version 302.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I swapped the cables to the video card... simple ... brilliant!