# Two screens/monitors in Linux console (FB not Xorg)

Tags: linux, console, intel-graphics, framebuffer

I try to 'mirror' a Linux console (not Xserver) from a Dell laptop to an external monitor connected with HDMI cable. The graphic card is Intel UHD 620. What's the best approach?

Initial net search indicates that KMS might be helpful. Is that correct?

This question seems to be similar to [Specify Monitor For Linux Console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45683/specify-monitor-for-linux-console), but that doesn't have clear answer.

Comment: Last time I looked at the Intel framebuffer driver, it didn't support HDMI outputs.

Comment: Interesting point. Where did you check it? Source?

Comment: Yes, in the source. Of course I may have overlooked it...

Comment: It seems to work with my old XPS'13 Dell. Will check it more extensively and add answer.

Comment: FYI @dirkt - looking for next thing (ensuring stable output resolution) I hit i915 kms docs which indicates support for hotplug-in  -https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/gpu/i915.html#hotplug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked on two different (Dell) laptops with i915 family graphic card. In both cases kernel with option described in https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Intel enable mirroring of a laptop screen on a remote monitor. I didn't need to do any configuration.

To make clear I was testing a text console, not Xserver. Both laptops didn't have Xserver at all.

Comment: Note that the i915 is the DRM driver, not the framebuffer driver, so you are sort of doing half an Xserver. And of course it works for X. It's interesting that this also works with the console, TIL.

Comment: @dirkt It was a console not Xserver. Adjusted my answer